# prove that $\left | g\right|=n$ iff $g^n=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra

prove that $\left | g\right|=n$ iff $g^n=e$   . I realize that this might be a very simple problem but i cannot find an explanation for it anywhere.
g is an element of a group G. And e is and identity

Comment: If $\mid g\mid=n,$ then $g^n=e,$ so $g^{2n}=e$ as well, hence $\mid g\mid=2n$?

Comment: its an if and only if statement

Comment: Please edit the question into the body --- it shouldn't just be in the title. Then, look for counterexamples --- you can hardly miss them.

Comment: i dont know of any

Comment: You might start by looking at a group of order not a prime.

Comment: Or you could let $g$ be the identity, and notice that $g^{73}=e$.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the comments, the claim is false. To give another example, consider the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, with elements $0$ and $1$. We have $1 + 1 = 0$ in this group, so perhaps $1$ should have order $2$. However, 
$$1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = (1+1) + (1+1) = 0 + 0 = 0$$

so should $1$ also have order $4$? By the same reasoning, we can argue that $1$ should have order $6,8, \cdots$. So clearly the statement above is false.

Now, you would like to intuitively say that $1$ should have order $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. At the same time, we have shown that

$$2(1) = 4(1) = 6(1) = 8(1) = \cdots = 0$$

So we need to distinguish $2$ from all the other possibilities, $4,6,8$, etc. What is it about $2$ that is different from all these other numbers (in this situation)? Can you see how this might be related to $\langle 1 \rangle$, the group generated by $1$?

More generally, if $g^{n} = e$ in a group, $g^{2n} = g^{n}g^{n} = ee = e$. An infinite family of powers will work! We need some way of distinguishing one power, preferably one that is connected to the properties of $\langle g \rangle$, the group generated by $g$.